# Store file in zip archive with different name (linux command shell)

Tags: linux, shell, compression

In a linux command line, you zip a file by:

```
zip -mqj archive.zip file.txt
```

Now, I need to store 'file.txt' as 'file2.txt' in 'archive.zip', without renaming the file before zipping. When unzipped, the file should be called 'file2.txt'.

How can I store the file with a different name? 
Read through the MAN page and didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does creating a hard link to file.txt count?

`ln file.txt file2.txt`

Create file2.txt which points to the exact same inode as file.txt, without actually doubling the space

Comment: For directories, this yields “hard link not allowed for directory”. However, a soft link (`-s`) seems to do the trick in that case.

Answer (score 14):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710341/linux-zip-command-add-a-file-with-different-name

**The solution below is the exact copy of the answer of [@mkrnr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2174538/mkrnr) on stackoverflow**

You can use zipnote which should come with the zip package.

First build the zip archive with the myfile.txt file:

```
zip archive.zip myfile.txt
```

Then rename myfile.txt inside the zip archive with:

```
printf "@ myfile.txt\n@=myfile2.txt\n" | zipnote -w archive.zip
```

(Thanks to [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648658/jens) for suggesting `printf` instead of `echo -e`.)

A short explanation of `"@ myfile.txt\n@=myfile2.txt\n"`:

From `zipnote -h`: "@ name" can be followed by an "@=newname" line to change the name

And `\n` separates the two commands.

Comment: For multiple renames, use the `zipnote file.zip` command to print a file skeleton that shows the syntax for multiple lines.

Answer (score 4):

Hy there, this is my first answer so I hope I've done everything correct :-)

Here's my solution to your problem, a nice one-liner:

```
cp file.txt file2.txt | zip -mqj archive.zip file2.txt
```

Hope I could help!

Comment: This is a good attempt, but the pipe is confusing. I think the person who asked didn't want to create a copy of the file first, but if he did, another way of doing this might be cp file.txt file2.txt && zip -mqj archive.zip file2.txt && rm -f file2.txt - this would clean up the temporary file2.txt that got created.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out - I would post this approach, too (but you already did, thanks!)

cp file.txt file2.txt && zip -mqj archive.zip file2.txt

(because of the -m switch the file already gets moved and there's no need to remove afterwards!)

Comment: Ah! Good call. I'm less familiar with zip than I am tar. thanks!

Comment: @Matt. Cant we just use mv instead of cp which wont create a copy, will rename the file, zip it and remove the copy to clear space. Just a thought.

Comment: @Viky - That would work fine, except one of the requests in the question was that we not rename the file. I think if we got more about the situation, a better answer would have presented itself, but as long as the person who asked the question is happy...